# Example of different solution set for a system of linear equations that each equation is a linear combination of another system

Tags: linear-algebra

In *Hoffman & Kunze Linear Algebra* book (Ch.1 Page 4), there is a saying that "if we have another system of linear equations in which each of the k equations is a linear combination of the equations from the main system, then every solution of the main system is a solution for the second system" (until that point I understand).

Then it says: "Of course it may happen that some solution of the second system are not solutions of the first system".

I can't think of an example, why is it true?

Comment: Suppose the original set of equations is independent, but the derived system has some dependent equations.

Comment: Can you provide an actual example?

Comment: $x=0, y=0$ has exactly one solution; $x+y=0, 2x+2y=0$ has an infinite number of them.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In forming these linear combinations, you might introduce dependencies that didn’t exist in the original system. A simple example: The system $x=0$, $y=0$ has a single solution; the system $x+y=0$, $2x+2y=0$ has an infinite number of them, including the solution of the original system.

Comment: In linear-algebraic terms, you might have introduced new dependencies so that the null space of the new system’s coefficient matrix is a superset of the null space of the original system’s matrix.